# Deploy TensorFlow model to server?

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, keras, streamlit

I am trying to deploy a Python ML app (made using Streamlit) to a server. This app essentially loads a NN model that I previously trained and makes classification predictions using this model.

The problem I am running into is that because TensorFlow is such a large package (at least 150MB for the latest tensorflow-cpu version) the hosting service I am trying to use (Heroku) keeps telling me that I exceed the storage limit of 300MB.

I was wondering if anyone else had similar problems or an idea of how to fix/get around this issue?

**What I've tried so far**

- I've already tried replacing the tensorflow requirement with tensorflow-cpu which did significantly reduce the size, but it was still too big so -
- I also tried downgrading the tensorflow-cpu version to tensorflow-cpu==2.1.0 which finally worked but then I ran into issues on model.load() (which I think might be related to the fact that I downgraded the tf version since it works fine locally)

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem last year. I know this does not answer your Heroku specific question, but my solution was to use Docker with AWS Beanstalk. It worked out cheaper than Heroku and I had less issues with deployment. I can guide on how to do this if you are interested

Comment: Would this method be able to support continuous deployment, and free? If it is I would appreciate some help getting it started!

Comment: [CI/CD](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/continuous-deployment-pipeline/) is possible. You can get free AWS credits [here](https://pages.awscloud.com/adoptf90d_GLOBAL_POC-credits?sc_channel=em&trkCampaign=eem20_recapsalllocs&trk=em_inv1_eem20_recapsalllocs_register&sc_campaign=EMEA_FIELD_WEBINAR_eemrecapsessions_20200127_7014z000001MKud&sc_medium=em_320544&sc_content=event_webinar_field&sc_geo=emea&sc_country=multi&sc_outcome=event).To Dockerize your app please view this [link](https://maelfabien.github.io/project/Streamlit/#requirements). Let me know if you get stuck!

Answer (score 0):

You might have multiple modules downloaded. I would recommend you to open file explorer and see the actual directory of the downloaded modules.

Comment: could you elaborate on this? What do you mean by multiple modules? I used a requirements.txt file to deploy so the only modules that get downloaded should be the modules in the requirements.txt file right?

Comment: I believe that sometimes you can have multiple copies of the same module. This happened to me with yfinance and messed stuff up.