# streamlit app with tensorflow model deploy

Tags: python, tensorflow, deployment, streamlit

I'm new to Python Streamlit, switching from R Shiny. I'm trying to deploy an app with a 300mb TensorFlow model for image prediction but Streamlit Community Cloud only supports 25mb files, and as I read here: [Deploy TensorFlow model to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65728247/deploy-tensorflow-model-to-server) , Heroku also have a big file size restriction.
Any cheap or free solutions to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by using GitHub with Git Large File Storage https://git-lfs.com/.
I had to install GitBash, create a local project and use Git LFS to upload the files to GitHub. Streamlit Community Cloud can access the model files from there.